# iPhone 5 and iPad css media queries

Tags: ipad, ios6, responsive-design, media-queries, iphone-5

Im working with a site with 3 views for desktop and iPad, both orientation one view,
and for iPhone/iPod a different one, the third is a warning to turn you device portrait, due the graphics can be better appreciated on that orientation, the issue is iPhone5 landscape gets a little of the iPad version, and with a little i mean it gets hide most of the stuffs but it doesn't show me the warning to rotate the device, any ideas or advice, this are the media queries.

```
/* ---------- iPhone/iPod Only Portrait ---------- */
@import url('../css/portrait.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait);
/* ---------- Retina iPhone/iPod Only Portrait ---------- */
@import url('../css/portrait.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2);
/* ---------- Non Retina iPhone/iPod Only Portrait ---------- */
@import url('../css/portrait.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1) and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1);
/* ---------- iPhone5 portrait Only ---------- */
@import url('../css/portrait.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2);


/* ---------- iPhone/iPod Only Landscape ---------- */
@import url('../css/landscape.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape);
/* ---------- Retina iPhone/iPod Only landscape ---------- */
@import url('../css/landscape.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2);
/* ---------- Non Retina iPhone/iPod Only landscape ---------- */
@import url('../css/landscape.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1) and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1);
/* ---------- iPhone5 landscape Only ---------- */
@import url('../css/landscape.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2);




/* ---------- iPad Only Portrait---------- */
@import url('../css/style_respond.css') only screen and (min-device-width:  768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait);
/* ---------- iPad Portrait Retina Device Only ---------- */
@import url('../css/style_respond.css') only screen and (min-device-width:  768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2);
/* ---------- iPad Portrait Non Retina Device Only ---------- */
@import url('../css/style_respond.css') only screen and (min-device-width:  768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1) and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1) ;


/* ---------- iPad Only landscape---------- */
@import url('../css/style_respond.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape); 
/* ---------- iPad landscape Retina Device Only ---------- */
@import url('../css/style_respond.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 2)and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) ;
/* ---------- iPad landscape Non Retina Device Only ---------- */
@import url('../css/style_respond.css') only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1)and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1) and (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1) ;

@import url('../css/style_respond.css') screen and (orientation:landscape) and (min-width: 1024px);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this with @import? Import css is not considered as efficient as @media screen method in same css file. You can define all responsive (either landscape or portrait ) rules for all devices(either iPhone, iPad or Desktop) within the same stylesheet.
Try this out for basic guidelines [Web Designer Blog on Mediaqueries.](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries).
And after that get all the device specific like- [iPhone 5 as well as iPad](http://www.stephentgilbert.com/mediaqueries/), gist from [here.](http://www.stephentgilbert.com/mediaqueries/)
Hope these'll hep you.